# Is there a way to filter out null values for literals and references

Tags: graphql, weaviate

If we have an Author with no beacons to Articles and thus *WroteArticles* was null and we wanted to only return Authors who had non-empty/non-null *WroteArticles*, how could that be done?

As an example we can use the Weaviate [demo site](http://playground.semi.technology/?weaviate_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdemo.dataset.playground.semi.technology%2Fv1%2Fgraphql&graphiql&gqlquery=%7B%0D%0A++Get+%7B%0D%0A++++Things+%7B%0D%0A++++++Article%28where%3A+%7B%0D%0A++++++++++++path%3A+%5B%22wordCount%22%5D%2C++++%23+Path+to+the+property+that+should+be+used%0D%0A++++++++++++operator%3A+GreaterThan%2C++%23+operator%0D%0A++++++++++++valueInt%3A+1000++++++++++%23+value+%28which+is+always+%3D+to+the+type+of+the+path+property%29%0D%0A++++++++%7D%29+%7B%0D%0A++++++++title%0D%0A++++++%7D%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A%7D)

I've tried filter operations using *where* and various *operators*, but I must be missing something obvious. Example of a query I've tried on my own data set below, where I did have a *Thing* with no beacons.

```
{
  Get {
    Things {
      Author (where:{
        operator:Equal,
        path:["WroteArticles"]
        valueString:" "
      }){
        name
        WroteArticles {
          ... on Article {
            InPublication {
              ... on Publication {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, this will be part of a new release, check: https://github.com/semi-technologies/weaviate/issues/1101

Comment: This was fixed in this release https://github.com/semi-technologies/weaviate/releases/tag/0.22.6

Comment: Yes, I will answer and close this one when it’s part of the docs 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now do this as follows (also in the [documentation](https://www.semi.technology/documentation/weaviate/current/query-data/filters.html#filter-by-count)):

```
{
 Get {
   Things {
     Author(
       where:{
         valueInt: 2
         operator:GreaterThanEqual
         path: ["WroteArticles"]
       }
     ) {
       name
       WroteArticles {
         ... on Article {
           title
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```